# I am really Confused in my below code of javascript..How does function actually working in it?

Tags: javascript

How does function actually working in it ?. tell me ?

```
var foo= 5/'randomString';
var voo= 'randomString';

 if (!Number.isNaN) {
    Number.isNaN = function(n) {
        return n !== n;
    };
}
```

Here i log in my browser and got this and strange result i got.

```
console.log(Number.isNaN( foo )); // true
console.log(Number.isNaN( voo )); // true

/* true(strange !) literally string is not 
       a number but also it is not definitely not the NaN
       value either! 
 */
```

Comment: Your result is wrong for voo. Cannot reproduce...

Comment: That implementation of isNaN is wrong....

Comment: **Why impemantation is wrong?**